# Why can't I use relative URLs with IE7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I've been Googling for a while and can't seem to find an answer to this question. My problem is as follows:

For my jquery, I need my links to be relative rather than absolute. My PHP is set to return relative urls and everything is working fine, until I test it in IE7. For some reason, IE7 keeps changing my relative urls to abosulute, which breaks my js script. Is this normal? Is there a way to get around it?

For example:

IE8, Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc -

```
<a href='/page' onclick='click_handler(this);return false;'>clicky</a>
```

IE7 -

```
<a href='http://www.myurl.com/page' onclick='click_handler(this);return false;'>clicky</a>
```

Comment: I think both your examples above are actually absolute URLs. A relative path would be something like ../../page.html or ./folder/page.html

Comment: umm . . . really? Surely the first one is relative as it is relative to the current domain. If that link was on google.com it would point ot http://www.google.com/page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I do is grab the baseUrl at init, like:

```
var baseUrl = window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

... and then in my URL handler, strip the baseUrl:

```
var url = $(this).attr("href").replace(baseUrl, "");
```

Also you can check if the href is "normalized" using `.support()`:

```
$.support.hrefNormalized
```

(returns `true` if the browser makes no modifications when grabbing an href value, so it's currently false in IE.)

Comment: +1 excellent answer. I modified it to use `var baseUrl = window.location.href.split('/').slice(0,3).join('/');` - slightly more concise and doesn't break on urls like `http://www.example.com/foo/bar/whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd use browser detection and add a clause to strip the URL down to the relative path. I'm not 100% familiar with jQuery, but I imagine you could do it with a simple split and reconstruction, or REGEX query.

See jQuery URL Parser Plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/url_parser

Comment: Good plan, except for the browser detection part. Just look at the url, and if it starts with http[s], strip that part of the url off.

Comment: Yeah this might be my only option. I was hoping there was a non Javascript solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has something to do with security issues - http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2005/08/15/452006.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Right, it seems the best way to do this is to strip the domain out in jQuery. For anyone that has a similar problem, here is what my click event handler looks like:

```
var href_attr = element.getAttribute('href');
if (href_attr.indexOf('http://')>-1) {
    href_attr = href_attr.substr(location.href.length-1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of JKS's answer that uses split instead of substring.  A little more elegant IMO:

```
stripBaseUrl : function(url){
    var urlArray = url.split("/");
    return urlArray[urlArray.length - 1];
}
```