# How to check if an appended <img /> src attribute is relative or absolute using jQuery & IE7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-7

I have a website that includes code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <img id="img_1" src="images/sample.gif" alt="Image 1" width="200" height="40" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this JavaScript and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrap').append('<img id="img_2" src="images/sample_2.gif" alt="Image 2" width="200" height="40" />');

    alert($('#img_1').attr('src'));
    alert($('#img_2').attr('src'));
});
```

In IE7,

the first alert displays: 'images/sample.gif'

the second alert displays: 'http://hostname/images/sample_2.gif'

Is there a work around for this?

What I'm doing is bringing in a header from a website on a different server through JSONP and appending it to the current page. The header includes relative paths for some img tags, so I want to selectively check if they are indeed relative and prepend the remote servers hostname so they correctly display.

The function works for every browser but IE7 because of this issue.

--

After doing some more work. I have this JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function Config(){}
        Config.Framework = {
            RemoteRoot: "http://remote-root.com/",
            RemoteHostName: "remote-root.com",
            LocalHostName: window.location.hostname
        };

        $('#wrap').append('<img id="img_2" src="images/logo.gif" alt="Logo" width="100" height="93" />');
        $('#wrap').append('<img id="img_3" alt="Logo" width="100" height="93" />');
        $('#img_3').attr("src", "images/logo.gif");

        $('img', '#wrap').each(function(i){
            set_src($(this));
            alert(i + ': ' + $(this).attr('src'))
        });

        function set_src(img) {
            var src = img.attr('src');

            if ($.inArray(Config.Framework.LocalHostName, src) > -1) {
                img.attr('src', src.replace(Config.Framework.LocalHostName, Config.Framework.RemoteHostName));
            } else {
                img.attr('src', Config.Framework.RemoteRoot + src);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

So the set_src function checks if the local hostname is in the src string, if it is, I replace it with the remote hostname. This is fine if the page that pulls in the image is at the root folder. But many times it is not.

If the image is pulled into a page that is not in the root directory, it will set the src as (only in IE7):

If in root directory it does:

- Original: 'http://local-hostname.com/images/logo.gif'
- After function: 'http://remote-root.com/images/logo.gif'

If outside root directory:

- Original: 'http://local-hostname.com/path/to/page/images/logo.gif'
- After function: 'http://remote-root.com/path/to/page/images/logo.gif'
- What I need: 'http://remote-root.com/images/logo.gif'

Comment: See [Why can’t I use relative URLs with IE7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774771/why-cant-i-use-relative-urls-with-ie7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add your images in jQuery like in the following code you will get relative url, so you won't need to check this, because all your images will be linked with relateve url:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#wrap').append('<img id="img_2" alt="Image 2" width="200" height="40" />');
    $('#img_2').attr("src","images/sample_2.gif");

alert($('#img_1').attr('src'));
alert($('#img_2').attr('src'));
});
</script>
```

Or you can check if the src contains "http":

```
alert($('#img_2').attr('src').indexOf("http"));
```

UPDATE:

I have modified your code. It relies on that the images will be in `"image"` folder.

```
function set_src(img) {
    var src = img.attr('src');
        alert(src);
        alert(src.indexOf('images/'));
    if (src.indexOf('/images/') > -1) {
            img.attr('src', src.replace(src.substring(0, src.indexOf('/images/') + 1),  Config.Framework.RemoteRoot));
        //img.attr('src', src.replace(Config.Framework.LocalHostName, Config.Framework.RemoteHostName));
    } else {
        img.attr('src', Config.Framework.RemoteRoot + src);
    }
        alert(img.attr('src'));
}
```

Comment: This does work.
But what I'm doing is grabbing all the markup of a remote <div id="header"> and appending it to a page. So I'm not really adding in one image at a time, but rather all of them at once. I then run through a function that checks if their src attributes are absolute or relative, and if relative, pre-append the remote's hostname to it. The IE7 problem arrises because every img src attribute is read as absolute.

Comment: I have updated my answer to replace the local host name. It will remove the local host name and all the folder names outside of the root folder, e.g. 'http://local-hostname.com/path/to/page' with ''http://remote-root.com/'.

Comment: I'm accepting this. This is basically the method I came to as well in a general sense. I had to do a few specific things as well for my specific use case.