# Internet Explorer 7 + MVC 3 = bad urls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer

This is weird. I say weird because on IE 8 and above (as well as FF) my urls generated by Html.ActionLink() creates an url in the correct form  -> http://mydomain.com/myapp/mycontroller/myaction **but** on IE 7 and IE8 running in compatibility mode the urls are generated as ->   http:///myapp/mycontroller/myaction . This is also affecting anything that uses Url.Content().

This is a concern because I have users still holding on to IE 7 for dear life (I don't get it either). Plus our Active Directory policy has things set for some (not all) users so that IE 8 is forced into compatibility mode and cannot be turned off. It also overrides the compatibility meta tag.

What should I check for here within MVC? Is there a web.config setting I need to look at?

**Code:**
Action links:

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Text", "Action", "Controller", new { Param1 = Model.Param1 }, new { @class = "linkButton" })

Url.Content:
Url.Content("~/Content/openHS.png")
```

**Update:**
I found a similar item dealing with this issue in PHP: [Why can't I use relative URLs with IE7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774771/why-cant-i-use-relative-urls-with-ie7)

A couple of other articles around the web mentioned using the `<base>` header tag.. trying this now. used the search "relative urls" "Internet explorer 7"

Comment: When the page containing the Html.ActionLink is rendered, what does the URL in the pages source look like?  Does it look like /Controller/Action or is it in the form of http://domain/app/controller/action?

Comment: Show the code for your Html.ActionLink() I believe that you are including domain in it.

Comment: @Andy: Hmm... both sources (IE8 in both compat and non-compat modes) rendered to /Controller/Action but the browser is interpreting it as I stated above.

Comment: Do you have a `base` tag in your `head` ?

Comment: The update was supposed to include base but I forgot to tag it as code..This is fixednow... To your question: I did however it did not include the domain. I'm still testing my solution if it works completely (including with Javascript) I'll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. I tested in WinXP mode with IE 8 in compatibility mode as well as in Internet Explorer 8 IE 7 mode, IE 9, IE9 Compat, FF 11.  No harm to my existing JavaScript

For Razor:

```
@{
     string baseHref;

     if(this.Request.Browser.Type == "IE7" && !this.Request.UserAgent.Contains("Trident/5.0"))
     {
          baseHref = this.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + this.Request.Url.Authority + Url.Content("~");
     }
     else 
     {
          baseHref = Url.Content("~");
     }
}
```

Then in the top of the `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;IE=8;" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<base href="@(baseHref)"/>
```

One explanation on the above: Trident/5.0 is IE 9's compatibility engine and seems to allow IE9 to interpret relative links according to the page domain instead of base. I'm sure you can remove the Razor code if you so choose. This was a compatibility patch for me.