# IE erroring on return View() where Chrome doing it correctly (ASP.Net MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, invalidoperationexception

I can't quite work out why a different browser would cause the server code to function differently, but in IE I'm getting an `InvalidOperationException`, whereas it's working perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

The code within `HomeController` (for a Facebook tab application, where some types have been renamed to obfuscate the client's name) reads:

```cs
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Nullable<long> facebookUserID = GetFacebookIDOrRedirect();

    Start start = new Start();
    start.FacebookUserID = facebookUserID;
    // More properties are set here...

    if (MyUser == null)
    {
        CurrentMyUser = new MyUser
        {
            UserID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            FacebookUserID = facebookUserID,
            Answers = new Dictionary<int, Answer>()
        };
    }
    else { start.SomeProperty = MyUser.SomeProperty; }

    ViewData.Model = start;
    // Some things are added to the ViewBag here.
    return View();
}
```

Now Chrome and Firefox are correctly going to the next method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Start(Start model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (CurrentMyUser == null) return View();

        MyUser myUser = (MyUser) Session["MyUser"];
        myUser.SomeProperty = model.SomeProperty;
        // More properties are set here...

        return RedirectToAction("Question", "MyController", new { id = 1 });
    }

    return View();
}
```

with a URL of `http://domain.com/MyController/Question/1`. In the same circumstances, though, IE is trying to access `http://domain.com/Home/Start`

Looking in the `Global.asax.cs`, there is no mention of `Start`; the only mention of the `HomeController` is below, as is the route that should be being called:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "FeedingTimes", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "FeedingTimes", action = "Question", id = 1 }
    // Parameter defaults
);
```

Fwiw, the browser version I can see it working in is the latest Chrome (19.0.1084.46 m) and it's failing in Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421. Our QA guys are telling me it's  working ok in Firefox and I'm not sure which IE version they're using, but they've already gone to lunch, so I can't ask.

This doesn't appear to be the same problem as [Internet Explorer 7 + MVC 3 = bad urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10089240/205245) or as [IE9 unexpected behaviour with MVC, IMG tag, Url.Action and TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8056552/205245) — looking in Fiddler, I get only the one request: `POST /Home/Start HTTP/1.1` (with the POSTdata I'd expect to see). But I can't see why IE would be doing it differently (or indeed why the server code would even be aware of the browser version!)

Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: In your `Start` method you have `if (CurrentMyUser == null) return View();` I guess with IE `CurrentMyUser` is null so it tries to access `/Home/Start`. So what is `CurrentMyUser` ? Or your `ModelState.IsValid` is false. You need to debug it...

Comment: @nemesv `CurrentMyUser` will have been populated by the preceding call to `Index(void)` (so `CurrentMyUser = new MyUser { ... };` in the first code excerpt). But that doesn't answer my fundamental question — if I'm accessing the functionality identically, except for the browser difference, how is it reacting differently?!

Comment: But where do you store `CurrentMyUser` session, cookie, cache? Because the browsers can have different settings for cookies. Also it can be some localization problem which can lead to `ModelState.IsValid` false. If you can debug your code to see whether `CurrentMyUser` is null or  `ModelState.IsValid` is false.

Comment: @nemesv `CurrentMyUser` is stored directly in the session. Both browsers are set up to accept cookies and are set up for the same locale (`en-GB`, with `Accept-Language:` fallback to `fr`, `de`, `es` and `cy`, as those are the languages I can read). I'll take a look at debugging those two variables now, though.

Comment: @nemesv As you predicted, `CurrentMyUser` is null when it shouldn't be. I'll keep investigating... Thanks!